# FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, filepicker.io, flutter-plugin

I am using `file_picker: ^1.7.1` this plugin working fine in android, but getting exception while using in real device iOS 13.4.1, getting FileSystemException while uploading a pdf file.

**Error Log**
`2020-04-29 15:56:04.991427+0530 Runner[4358:1416983] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0C1997E5-5243-494E-85EA-830E3248CC97/tmp/com.vassar.bluis-Inbox/https:%2Ffoodlicensing.fssai.gov.in%2FREG%2FRG_ViewReceipt.aspx?ReqID=68198366.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

```
#0 _File.length. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:376:9)
#1 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#2 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#3 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#4 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
```

**Flutter Version details**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287,
locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/teja/flutter_dev/flutter
• Framework revision f139b11009 (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
• Engine revision af51afceb8
• Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/teja/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
• CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• Shahnawaz’s iphone • d59a055eb9bbddc9be958142d9c484e3c45bbf2f • ios • iOS
13.4.1

• No issues found
```

Comment: Have you given respected permission on both Android and iOS ?

Comment: For android it is working fine, I am not sure about iOS permission for reading directory/file.@Ra

Comment: You need to make the permission entry in iOS like we do in the Manifest in Andorid case

Comment: Yeah I have given permission as required @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: @MdShahnawaz any update on this?

Comment: @SudipPodder [Check this github issue](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/261#issuecomment-648812821)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it there was an issue with the Flutter `file_picker`. **Updating it should be a good fix**.

Since `iOS 13` you need to request access to files outside your app sandbox, via `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` if not, you will see that `length` or `open` issue even though you do have a valid file path.

You can find more info in [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories) which actually applies to files too.